# for Azure websites, do you need to keep the awverify DNS records?

Tags: azure

I managed to get my custom subdomain name assigned to my Azure website, following this (very carefully):

[link to azure custom domain name instructions](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-custom-domain-name/)

Is it necessary to keep the "awverify" DNS records after the custom domain names linkage has been established?

I deleted the awverify DNS record for the test subdomain, and was able to add another subdomain pointer to my azurewebsites test site.

Maybe I did not wait long enough.  Does anyone else have any experience with this, to say one way or the other?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure if I understand the issue you are running into... but the CNAME entry with the 'awverify' subdomain is used to "prove" to Azure that you own that domain when you are wiring up a custom domain name. Once that is established, you no longer need that.

Comment: Yep, I reverified that this morning.  Didn't really have an issue, just wanted confirmation, and thought it would be useful to get a confirmed answer on record.  I was concerned about all those unneeded awverify DNS records that could be piling up out there (including mine)! :-)